# How to fix the number of prefabs that the ARCore can display at the same time ? (with image recognition)

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, image-recognition, arcore

the current application allows you to detect posters and display, at the size of the poster, a plane on which a video is launched.

My problem is that there is sound in the videos and that, for example, if you look at 3 posters at the same time, you don't understand anything anymore.

I'm wading to try either to enable the sound of the video the user is watching, or to limit the number of videos that are displayed at the same time (like waiting for the first video to finish before displaying another video)

I am currently using unity 2019.1.6
with arcore version 1.10.0 for an android build

I tried to use a system via trigger, then by Raycast but nothing to do, I still have the sound and the videos are all displayed.

```c#
[SerializeField] private VideoClip[] videoClips;
public AugmentedImage Image;
private VideoPlayer video;

void Start()
{
    video = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    video.loopPointReached += OnStop;
}

private void OnStop(VideoPlayer source)
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!video.isPlaying)
    {
        video.clip = videoClips[Image.DatabaseIndex];
        video.Play();
    }

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(Image.ExtentX - 1, Image.ExtentZ, 1);
}
```

I have rather strange results, either the videos no longer appear but there is the sound of the videos, or nothing is displayed.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully know your code and setup but I would simply check the angle between the direction in which the User is looking and the vector between the user and the image. Something like e.g.

```c#
[Tooltip("Angle in degrees between view direction and positions vector has to be smaller than this to activate the video")]
[SerializeField] private float angleThreshold = 20f;

// if possible already reference this via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

void Start()
{
    if(!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

void Update()
{
    // get positions vector
    var direction = (Image.CenterPose.position - mainCamera.transform.position).normalized;
    // get view direction
    var viewDirection = mainCamera.transform.forward;
    // get angle between them
    var angle = Vector3.Angle(viewDirection, direction);

    // optionally you could use only the X axis for the angle check 
    // by eliminating the Y value of both vectors
    // allowing the user to still look up and down 
    //direction = (new Vector3(Image.CenterPose.position.x, 0, Image.CenterPose.position.z) - new Vector3(mainCamera.transform.position.x, 0 , mainCamera.transform.position.z)).normalized;
    //viewDirection = new Vector3(viewDirection.x, 0, viewDirection.z);

    // also check the angle
    if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking || angle > angleThreshold)
    {
        // optional: I would also stop the video if no longer in focus
        if (video.isPlaying && video.clip == videoClips[Image.DatabaseIndex]) video.Stop();
        return;
    }

    if (!video.isPlaying)
    {
        video.clip = videoClips[Image.DatabaseIndex];
        video.Play();
    }

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(Image.ExtentX - 1, Image.ExtentZ, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hello,
my set up and code is close (almost copy and paste) to this tutorial video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkzMFNmvums

And great idea, until now I was absolutely trying to solve my problems using unity tools when....I could just do math. 
When you wear blinders ^^